# In my Android app, I use a SparseArray where I put data into it and immediate get it, sometimes the data is null

Tags: java

I use a SparseArray mapping ints to Objects. I put the Objects into the SparseArray and immediately retrive them in a different method. However, occasionally this returns null. I want a method that will wait until the retrieved value is not null to retrieve it.

Comment: Provide the code which put and retrive values. If you do this in the same thread you should get correct value